# I try to build a docker container that include externals files

Tags: docker, dns, dockerfile, docker-container, bind9

I try to create a docker container with bind9 on it and I want to add my db.personal-domain.com file but when I run `docker build` and then `docker run -tdp 53:53 -v config:/etc/bind <image id>` the container doesn't have my db.personal-domain.com file. How to fix that ? Thanks !

**tree structure**

```
-DNS
--Dockerfile
--config
---db.personal-domain.com
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y bind9
RUN apt-get install -y bind9utils

WORKDIR /etc/bind
VOLUME ["/etc/bind"]

COPY config/db.personal-domain.com /etc/bind/db.personal-domain.com


EXPOSE 53/tcp

CMD ["/usr/sbin/named", "-g", "-c", "/etc/bind/named.conf", "-u", "bind"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax issue in your `docker run -v` option.  If you use `docker run -v name:/container/path` (even if `name` matches a local file or directory) it mounts a [named volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) over your configuration directory.  You want the host content, and you need `-v /absolute/host/path:/container/path` syntax (the host path must start with `/`).  So (on Linux/MacOS):

```sh
docker run -d -p 53:53 \
  -v "$PWD:config:/etc/bind" \
  my/bind-image
```

In your image you're trying to `COPY` in the config file.  This could work also; but it's being hidden by the volume mount, and also rendered ineffective by the `VOLUME` statement.  (The most obvious effect of `VOLUME` is to prevent subsequent changes to the named directory; it's not required to mount a volume later.)

If you delete the `VOLUME` line from the Dockerfile, it should also work to run the container without the `-v` option at all.  (But if you'll have different DNS configuration on different setups, this probably isn't what you want.)

Answer (score 1):

```
-v config:/etc/bind
```

That syntax creates a named volume, called `config`. It looks like you wanted a host volume pointing to a path in your current directory, and for that you need to include a fully qualified path with the leading slash, e.g. using `$(pwd)` to generate the path:

```
-v "$(pwd)/config:/etc/bind"
```